# What is the correct value of Neuronal Resting Potential - is it -65mV or -70mV?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, action-potential

Some books show the resting potential of neurons as **-65mV**, such as *Neuroscience: Exploring the Brain*, Fourth Edition (2016, published by Wolters Kluwer).

[image: Graph from page 84, showing the resting potential at -65]

However, a majority of internet sites, including Wikipedia, show the resting potential as **-70mV**.

**Which one of these is the correct value, and why is there this small difference**?

Comment: This seems a rather specialized question. Why are you concerned about what you admit is a small difference? Does it have any practical relevence to your work? We would be interested to know.

Comment: @David I  was just reading about the resting potential of the neurons in the book mentioned above.The book uses -65mV in all the pages ,when i checked the internet ,it is -70mV everywhere.So i was curious.

Comment: @David **Why are you concerned about what you admit is a small difference?**  I am new to the field so i was confused.  ** Does it have any practical relevence to your work?**  No,I am not building anything,just reading only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is incorrect. Neuronal resting potential is a function of the internal and external concentrations of ions and the conductance of the membrane to those ions via ion channels. Different neurons exhibit a range of resting potentials.

You can calculate the resting potential for a given cell using the [Goldman Equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldman_equation).